# Make a sum() of column accessors Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, accessor

im improving my skills in laravel making a simple challenges web but i stuck on the next problem.

I have the users table with the id, name, mail, etc. The challenges table where i list all the challenges (with columns id, name, body, answer, score) and a third table called "Answers" where i post each try of the users solving a challenge with the columns id, user_id, challenge_id, success (boolean) and score.

Now i'am trying to make a ranking of users with their scores. The problem is to show a sum() of the column 'score' in the table answers where user_id.answers = users.id. So i can get easy the total score for each user.

For now i solved the problem doing this in blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
<th>{{ $user->id }}</th>
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
<td>Team pindonga</td>
<td>{{ score = DB::table('answers')->where('user_id', $user->id)->sum('score') }} </td> </tr>
@endforeach
```

works perfectly, but i want to get them by desc score (for now i solved the desc with js but want to get desc order from the eloquent query) and have something like this in the blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
<th>{{ $user->id }}</th>
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
<td>Team pindonga</td>
<td>{{ $team->score }} </td> </tr>
@endforeach
```

I was thinking about solve it with accessors doing something like this:

```
public function getScoreAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->groupBy('user_id')->where('user_id', '=', $value)->sum('score');
}
```

also i have a relationship belongsTo in the answers modle to users and a hasMany in the users to answers. But i'm not sure of how pass the results to blade. Tried in tinker:

```
    >>> \App\Answer::find(1)->score;
=> "3400"
>>> \App\Answer::find(2)->score;
=> "3400"
>>> \App\Answer::find(5)->score;
=> "3400"
```

allways getting the sum of the id = 1. And with $user->score; in the blade foreach i got a '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the relationship with Blade would be `{{ $user->answers->sum('score') }}`. No accessor needed.

For sorting I would use the [sortByDesc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortbydesc) collection method.

```
$users = User::get();

$users = $users->sortByDesc(function ($user) {
  return $user->answers->sum('score');
});
```

Comment: Work perfect. I did

            $users = $users->sortByDesc(function ($user) {
              return $user->answers->sum('score');
            });
in the controller and {{ $user->answers->sum('score') }} to show the score in the blade.

I'll try to add categorys for the challenges now. wish me luck :P

Comment: should be $user->answers()->sum(......) instead of $user->answers->sum(......)
->answers() return a query builder, why ->answer will actually execute the query to get all answers of a user and then count the number of model

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. It takes a while to get used to Eloquent ORM :-)

```
foreach($users as $user){
  print $user->answers->sum('score');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#aggregates